# All integers $m$ satisfying $m\equiv n^2 \mod 19$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

> 1. How to find all Integers $m$ satisfying $m\equiv n^2 \mod 19$ for some $n\in Z$ ?
> 2. For each non-zero element of $Z_{19}$, find its order (in the multiplicative group of this ring).

I don't know how to do both. For the first one, taking all $a$ from $0$ to $19$ we can check some $x$. I got all values of $a$, but don't know what is the general procedure to be followed.

I guess the answers of $a$ should be $a=\left\{0,1,4,5,6,7,9,11,16,17\right\}.$

Comment: If you take each and add $19k,$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z},$ your answer for 1) would be valid. Note want *all* such integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic.

The order of $x\in\Bbb Z_{19}^*$ divides $18$ (the order of the group).

Now, there are $\varphi (18)=6$ generators.

By process of elimination,  there are $\varphi(3)=2$ elements of order $3$.  They are $\{7,12\}$.

Next, there are $\varphi (6)=2$ of order $6$.  They are $\{8,11\}$.

There are $\varphi (9)=6$ elements of order $9$. We can take them from the list in part $a)$, since a square can't generate. Those are:  $\{4,9,16,6,17,5\}$.

Now we can do the $6$ generators: 
   $\{2,3,10,13,14,15\}$.

The only one left is $\{18\}$, which has order $2$.

Comment: You're right.  I made a mistake.   I interchanged the order $9$ and order $18$ elements.   Let me correct.  @OscarLanzi

Answer (score 5):

1. We can just take the residues of $0^2,1^2,2^2,\cdots, 9^2$, see here:

[For an odd prime $p$, prove that the quadratic residues of $p$ are congruent modulo $p$ to the integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156620/for-an-odd-prime-p-prove-that-the-quadratic-residues-of-p-are-congruent-mod)

So these are $m=1,4,9,16,6,17,11,7,5$ as quadratic residues modulo $19$. Furthermore $m=0$ is a square.

Comment: The next one is $5^2=25=6$ in $\Bbb Z/19$. And so on.

Comment: can you please help me out with 2nd question ?

Comment: By Lagrange, the order of the elements of $U(19)\cong C_{18}$ are divisors of $18$. For example, $m=2$ has order $18$, since $2^{18}=1$ in $\Bbb Z/19$, but no smaller positive power of $2$. Please consult this site, it is solved here already. Search for exmaple, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229135/u19-cyclic-subgroups) first.